# can not load modules with webpack (Module not found: Error)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to build react components on Ruby on Rails app. I put webpack environment in `/client`, and put bundled files into`/app/assets/javascripts/webpack/`. But when i start webpack and try to build components, it says `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /components/favorite_box`. Following is my code. Please teach me what is the problem.

#### Directory

```
client
├─ src
│   ├ components
│   │    └─ favorite_box.js.jsx
│   └─index.js
├─ node_modules
├─ package.json
└─ webpack.config.js
```

#### File Components

favorite_box.js.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

export default class FavoriteBox extends React.Component {
 // ...

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="FavoriteBox">
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import FavoriteBox from './components/favorite_box.js.jsx'

ReactDOM.render(
  <FavoriteBox/>,
  document.getElementById('favorite_box')
)
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js',
  },

  output: {
    path: '../app/assets/javascripts/webpack',
    filename: '[name].js',
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: "babel",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ["es2015", "react"],
        }
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "webpack-watch": "webpack -w",
    "webpack-build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not spotting anything right away, expect for the `favorite_box.js.jsx` doesn't seem like you should need both extensions, that might be causing issue with it's resolver. It might be better to just use `.js` or `.jsx`

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I renamed `favorite_box.js.jsx` to `favorite_box.jsx`, but the same error occurs... Maybe the problem is on elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe try setting `context` to `path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')`

Comment: i set up the project exactly as you did, and everything worked for me. maybe try removing node_modules, then `npm install`, and try webpack again?

Comment: also, the error message should contain a path at the end, see if it is the `client` folder. `Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./components/favorite_box.jsx in /somepath/app_name/client/src`

Comment: I don't know why but now favorite_box is displayed correctly. I renamed I renamed favorite_box.js.jsx to favorite_box.jsx and did `npm install` again. I appreciate your help.